# How to easily check how many laser scanner samples are being generated by the ray plugin?

Tags: ros-humble, gazebo-plugin, gazebo-11, 2dlaserscan

Is there an easy way to check how many laser scanner samples are being generated by the ray plugin? I know I can check it in the URDF, XACRO or SDF but I want to confirm it by looking at the messages.

I'm aware that I can create a node that subscribes to the `/scan` topic and do `.size()` to the vector of msgs. I wonder if there's a built-in option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you are trying to count how many lasers are being used in the ray plugin just checking the topic published with a `LaserScan` msg.

I think you could use the `angle_min` and `angle_max` with `angle_increment` in order to know the samples used.

In case you want to know the actual samples in each message (perhaps some laserscans are being skipped by inf values or whatever) I find interesting to use the flag `--noarr`. This flag omits the arrays and just shows the type  of the data as well as the length of the arrays (in this case, check ranges). The use of it would be as simple as:
`rostopic echo /<scan_topic> --noarr`

Resulting in:

> ````
> header:
>   seq: 276
>   stamp: 
>     secs: 29
>     nsecs: 851000000
>   frame_id: "os0_lidar"
> angle_min: 0.0
> angle_max: 3.14159011841
> angle_increment: 0.00870000012219
> time_increment: 0.0
> scan_time: 0.0500000007451
> range_min: 0.10000000149
> range_max: 20.0
> ranges: "<array type: float32, length: 362>"
> intensities: "<array type: float32, length: 0>"```
> ````

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for!

For ROS 2 would be: 

`ros2 topic echo /<scan_topic> --no-arr`

Comment: This doesn't seem to result in the *number* of laser scans though, which is what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ros2 topic echo /scan` to view the topic on the command line quickly.

Comment: That doesn't tell you how many sample are being generated right away. You need to count them by hand or using another program.

Comment: @andrestoga - I'm not familiar with the output format of `ros2 topic echo /scan` but couldn't you use pipe it into grep (or sed or awk) to get an effective one line per sample and then pipe to `wc -l` to count the lines, something like this: `ros2 topic echo /scan | grep <search term> | wc -l`? Obviously replacing `<search term>` with something that results in *one line per sample*.

Comment: I guess so but I was looking for a built-in solution.

Asked ChatGPT to do it with pipes as you said but it didn't work lol

Comment: @andrestoga -  That's not surprising, if you used ChatGPT (which just regurgitates nonsense). Note that ChatGPT is rather frowned upon, here on Stack Exchange... I wouldn't even mention it in future.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the output of `ros2 topic echo /scan`, having never used it.

However, after a google, I found this, [laser data is not avliable on rviz2 . but i am geting data while using terminal cmd topic echo.](https://answers.ros.org/question/412061/laser-data-is-not-avliable-on-rviz2-but-i-am-geting-data-while-using-terminal-cmd-topic-echo/), which shows an example of the output, like so:

```
header: stamp: sec: 1675073473 nanosec: 112333930 frame_id: laser angle_min: 0.0 angle_max: 6.2657318115234375 angle_increment: 0.01745329238474369 time_increment: 0.0005592841189354658 scan_time: 0.20134228467941284 range_min: 0.11999999731779099 range_max: 3.5 ranges: - 0.13099999725818634 - 0.12999999523162842 - 0.12999999523162842 - 0.1289999932050705 - 0.1289999932050705 - 0.1289999932050705 - 0.1289999932050705 - 0.1289999932050705 ................
```

So, assuming that each sample "message" has the text `header` at the start, then this command *should*<sup>1</sup> count your samples:

```bash
ros2 topic echo /scan | grep header | wc -l
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Unless I've got completely the wrong end of the stick